# Javascript form field validation not working?

Tags: javascript, validation, forms, field

im doing a simple website for a university project, and one of the requirements is that i have javascript to validate the form fields input. I've implimented what i believe to be a working solution (took it off the W3C website) but it won't seem to run at all?

The HTML page is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>Rubber Toy Dept. Inc. Ltd.</title>
    <link href="css/layout.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/java/validation.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div  id="wrapper">
        <div id="header">
            <h1 id="headlines">Rubber Toy Dept. Inc. Ltd. </h1>
        </div>

        <div id="content">
            <div id="content-main">
                <form action="mailto:gt70@hw.ac.uk" onsubmit="return validate_form(thisform)"  method="post">
                    <table width="858" border="0px">
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <input type="checkbox" name="cb1" value="1"></input>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                Daniel
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                &pound;90
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <a href="productpages/daniel.xhtml"><img src="pics/daniel_sml.jpg" width="75" height="75" alt="Daniel"></img></a>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                              <tr>
                            <td>
                                <input type="checkbox" name="cb2" value="1"></input>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                Graeme
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                &pound;80
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <a href="productpages/graeme.xhtml"><img src="pics/graeme_sml.jpg" width="75" height="75" alt="Graeme"></img></a>
                            </td>
                          </tr>
                              <tr>
                            <td>
                                <input type="checkbox" name="cb3" value="1"></input>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                Lewis
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                &pound;10
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <a href="productpages/lewis.xhtml"><img src="pics/lewis_sml.jpg" width="75" height="75" alt="Lewis"></img></a>
                            </td>
                          </tr>
                              <tr>
                            <td>
                                <input type="checkbox" name="cb4" value="1"></input>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                Conor
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                &pound;1 (bargain!)
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <a href="productpages/conor.xhtml"><img src="pics/conor_sml.jpg" width="75" height="75" alt="Conor"></img></a>
                            </td>
                          </tr>
                        </table>

                    <table width="858" border="0px">
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                Username
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <input type="text" name="username" id="username"></input>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                E-mail Address
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <input type="text" name="email" id="email"></input>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                Address
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <input type="text" name="address" id="address"></input>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td></td>
                            <td>
                                <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit"></input>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </form>
            </div>

            <div id="w3c">
                <a href="http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=referer"><img src="http://www.w3.org/Icons/valid-xhtml10" alt="Valid XHTML 1.0 Transitional" height="31" width="88" /></a>
            </div>

            <div id="footer">
                <i>Coded and Designed by G.A Tinsdale, D. Scott and L. Mclean</i>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div id="bottom">
        </div>
    </div>  
</body>
```

and the Javascript file contains:

```
function validate_required(field,alerttxt)
        {
            with (field)
            {
                if (value==null||value=="")
                {
                    alert(alerttxt);
                    return false;
                }
                else
                {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }

        function validate_form(thisform)
        {
            with (thisform)
            {
                if (validate_required(email,"Email must be filled out!")==false)
                {
                    email.focus();
                    return false;
                }

                if (validate_required(username,"Username must be filled out!")==false)
                {
                    username.focus();
                    return false;
                }

                if (validate_required(address,"Address must be filled out!")==false)
                {
                    address.focus();
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
```

Sorry if i've laid out the code wrong... i don't seem to understand how to do it properly :(

Thanks for any help given

Daniel.

Comment: By the way, your browser should have given you error messages for this page that would have been along the lines of "object not found: validation".  And if you didn't get useful messages, get a better browser for this kind of work!  Paying attention to this output will help you pinpoint errors more easily.

Comment: It's sorted now. Thanks to everyone who helped out :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### **Update:**

There is 404 error for your validation file as rightly pointed out by @Matthew Wilson :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="script/java/validation.js">
       ----------------------------------------^
```

Make sure that you are specifying the correct path and the file exists.

---

Problem here:

```
onsubmit="return validation.js:validate_form(thisform)"
```

Should be:

```
onsubmit="return validate_form(thisform)"
```

Comment: Indeed.  When you reference an external JS file, all of its global declarations are imported into the page's namespace, so they don't need to be prefixed with the script name.

Comment: Ok, but that still doesn't seem to work. Ive uploaded the files here, and you can check for yourself? http://rvddps.com/Updated%20Structure/index.xhtml

Comment: There's a 404 error from the attempt to load the Javascript file.

Comment: It seems to say there's an error with the   with (field) line in the javascript? i have no idea what that is though?

Comment: 'with' is a pretty nasty construct and can lead to subtle errors. It should probably be OK here though.

Comment: I just took the code off of the W3C's example code on how to do it, i'd expect that code to work?

Comment: Ok, the script placement was wrong, but it still wont execute the JS even after i changed it?

Comment: Yes, I just wanted to say that I didn't think it was good practice.

Comment: Try taking "<script>" and "</script>" out of the .js file - they don't belong there, only in the HTML.

Comment: Just took them out, no difference made.

Comment: OK, now you're calling "validate_form(thisform)" but "thisform" isn't defined. Try "validate_form(this)".

Comment: @Matthew Wilson: Credit goes to you for your effort and comments while I was busy elsewhere. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you included the script file in the  of the page:
`<script type="text/javascript" src="validation.js"></script>`. Next remove `validation.js:` from your form's onsubmit... that's not needed. If it still doesn't work, so some debugging. Stick an alert('form submitted') in your validate form function, and see if it fires. If not, you need to work out why, and if it does, put an alert further down the function tree to find out what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the URL you have given you have script tags all wrong

Line 7

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="script/java/validation.js">
```

Should be

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="script/java/validation.js"></script>
```

Line 8

```
<script>
```

should be

```
<script type="text/javascript">
```

And remove the extra script tag on line 50

```
</script>
```

Comment: The default type for a <script> tag is always "text/javascript", the page may not be standards compliant without them but it'll still be functional

Comment: With HTML5 I don't believe you need the type attribute at all, but this is XHTML, so it is a required attribute for this doctype, although I think it only impacts HTML Validation, as modern browsers will still execute the block as JavaScript. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5265202/do-you-need-text-javascript-specified-in-your-script-tags