# Do you need text/javascript specified in your <script> tags?

Tags: javascript, html

I read somewhere that you no longer need things like `type="text/javascript"` and the weird `CDATA` and `<!--` things in your script tags. So, instead of:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
<!--

    //your script here

-->
//]]>
</script>
```

You would just do:

```
<script>
    //your script here
</script>
```

I can't remember where I read this though. It was from a Google or Yahoo engineer I think, and they specifically mentioned which browsers required these archaic constructs and why. Anyone know what blog post/article this was talked about, or have a good resource talking about this?

Comment: For new browsers, but on older (if such still exist) <!-- --> is needed. About the type in some apps if not omited, needs the right one.

Comment: Good read about CDATA: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/66837/when-is-a-cdata-section-necessary-within-a-script-tag

Comment: Everytime I open up a file with `text/javascript` specified, I remove it. It's noise.

Comment: A very related post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4195427/465053) having up-to-date information about HTML5 guidelines in the accepted answer.

Comment: As already said in many answers, HTML5 doesn't need the `type="text/javascript"`, but I want to point out that the W3C Validator generates a warning if you specify it.

Answer (score 152, accepted):

See [Crockford's write-up on the `<script>` tag](https://www.crockford.com/javascript/script.html), most notably:

> Do not use the `<!-- //-->` hack with scripts. It was intended to prevent scripts from showing up as text on the first generation browsers Netscape 1 and Mosaic. It has not been necessary for many years. `<!-- //-->` is supposed to signal an HTML comment. Comments should be ignored, not compiled and executed. Also, HTML comments are not to include `--`, so a script that decrements has an HTML error.

...

> #### `type="text/javascript"`

This attribute is optional. Since Netscape 2, the default programming language in all browsers has been JavaScript. In XHTML, this attribute is required and unnecessary. In HTML, it is better to leave it out. The browser knows what to do.

Comment: this actually *might* be the article I'm remembering

Comment: Required _and_ unnecessary?  Am I missing something?

Comment: @Izkata, it's required for validation, but doesn't have any effect.

Comment: "The browser knows what to do" ... for now.  What about next week when RubyScript (I made this up as an example) is popularized and everybody craps their pants to adopt it?  This is the same kind of short-sighted thinking that makes people name their files "_new" and confuses other people for years.  Is it the "_new"?  Or "_new_new"?  Or "_newer"?  IMO it's short-sighted.

Comment: @Slobaum, the HTML5 spec states that it [defaults to JavaScript](http://developers.whatwg.org/scripting-1.html#attr-script-type).  If there are new script types, they'll only be implemented in new browser versions that support that default from the spec.

Comment: @bdukes And the browsers always get it right and never do their own thing, thus mucking things up :)  I'm really just saying I prefer being explicit rather than implicit.  I understand we're trying to force adoption of the spec by just doing things correctly, and that's great.  But I'm more concerned that my employers applications continue run correctly rather than trying to drive a paradigm shift.

Comment: if `RubyScript` becomes popular, it will end in `.rbscript` and the browser will act accordingly.

Comment: @KirkStrobeck - Not when it's an inline script, but then you'd just add `type="text/rubyscript"` to override the default script type.

Comment: @Slobaum Ok. I get where you are coming from, but why not `type="javascript"` instead of `type="text/javascript"`

Comment: For anyone wondering what is meant by: "In XHTML, this attribute is required and unnecessary." I think it means that nobody uses XHTML anymore, so it's unnecessary to worry about it.

Comment: @Ringo: XHTML 5 is alive and well. XHTML 5 is part of the HTML 5 specification as the syntactically simpler and stricter serialization of the HTML 5 DOM as XML, and is the version you should use if you want to take advantage of XML tools (e.g. xpath, xslt, libxml, namespaces) to process your HTML. Many people uses XHTML 5 every day.

Comment: @LieRyan Good to know. So was my interpretation of Crockford incorrect?

Comment: @Ringo: I don't think your interpretation of Crockford is correct. IMO, bdukes's interpretation is more plausible. Another possible interpretation is that it's unnecessary because the XHTML spec could've specified it as defaulting to text/javascript if missing. Unlike many other XHTML differences which are due to XML idiosyncrasies, making type required is something that could've been made optional just quite easily in XML.

Comment: Just do this `<script src="/includes/js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>`. No need for `text/javascript`

Comment: @LieRyan I think it'd be somewhat misleading to say "XHTML is alive and well." Historically speaking, it was, in fact, a competitor to HTML5. There are countless blog posts and websites from 5 years ago that discussed the difference between the two. For example:    http://www.dummies.com/web-design-development/html/the-relationship-between-html5-and-xhtml/ 

To suggest that this competition didn't exist would be inaccurate.

Comment: @Ringo: your knowledge of XHTML is about a decade expired if you think that way. XHTML 1.1 and XHTML 2 are very different beast than XHTML 5. If you always put quotes around your attributes, if you always balance your `<p>` and `<li>`, and if you use self closing tags for tags that must be empty, then what you're writing is more XHTML 5 than it is HTML 5.

Comment: @Ringo: There are not many people outside the people involved in the standard groups and browser developers who truly knows how HTML 5 syntax works, it is just too complex to use for most people. Most good HTML 5 developers really are writing a [polyglot flavour](https://dev.w3.org/html5/html-polyglot/), which is just missing a few formalities (e.g. explicit namespace declaration, Content-Type header) to become proper XHTML 5.

Comment: @LieRyan I appreciate the knowedge, but I still think you're underplaying the historical significance of older versions of XHTML, as it were. It's fine that parts of XHTML were absorbed by HTML5, I can appreciate that.

Comment: [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_script_type.asp):

 ```In HTML5, the type attribute is no longer required for JavaScript. The default value is "application/javascript".```

Comment: @Slobaum writing to you from 2019 - where RubyScript has yet to come into existence.

Comment: @itamar 2022 now, still no RubyScript, thank the gods. I wouldn't mind type "text/TypeScript" at this point ;) it's interesting to see how the perspective on this has changed over the years. Now we have WebAssembly, we have a much better picture of how other capabilities can be enabled. Given how the browsers have changed, I reckon external scripts certainly don't need a type defined; the HTTP header will do so. All these many years later I still add "type='text/JavaScript'" but at this point it's purely pedantic. The browsers have known what to do for a minute now.

Answer (score 48):

It's a [Crockford](http://www.crockford.com) recommendation. I know I've seen it echoed elsewhere (ppk maybe?).  The HTML5 spec does not require it.

Oddly, it's become somewhat *au courant* to use the "type" attribute to mark `<script>` blocks that you **don't** want to be evaluated:

```
<script type='text/html-template'>
  <div> this is a template </div>
</script>
```

By giving a weird non-JavaScript type, you get a way to stuff raw text into the page for use by other JavaScript code (which is presumably in script block that **can** be evaluated).

Comment: i cant understand fully. please explain, what does `type="text/html"` means at all, and what does `text/javascript` means.. thanks

Comment: @tazotodua it's not really very important what "text/html" means; the important thing is that it is **not** "text/javascript", browsers will completely ignore the contents of the `<script>` block. However, the `<script>` *will* become part of the DOM, so other JavaScript code can find them and extract their contents.

Comment: That's an interesting hack. Not sure what I'd use it for, though.

Comment: [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_script_type.asp):

 ```In HTML5, the type attribute is no longer required for JavaScript. The default value is "application/javascript".```

Comment: Ten years have passed (time of writing) and what is achieved in the example with decoy type is now native using `<template>` tag. Just bonus hint.

Comment: @TechNyquist yes, true, but the contents of a `<template>` block must be valid; the contents of a `<script type=text>` can be *anything*, like JSON, or a partial HTML section, etc.

Answer (score 19):

HTML5 doesn't need the `type="text/javascript"` (it's the default).

`CDATA` is only neeed for XHTML pages, if the script has any HTML characters (like '<' and '>') in it.

`<!--` should only be needed for OLD browsers.

Answer (score 4):

The **[type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script)** attribute identifies the scripting language of code embedded within a script element or referenced via the element’s src attribute. This is specified as a MIME type; examples of supported MIME types include text/javascript, text/ecmascript, application/javascript, and application/ecmascript.

According to [HTML 4.01 Specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/scripts.html#h-18.2.1)

> The **type** attribute specifies the scripting language of the element's
>   contents and overrides the default scripting language. The scripting
>   language is specified as a content type (e.g., "text/javascript").
>   Authors must supply a value for this attribute. There is no default
>   value for this attribute.

But in [HTML5](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/scripting-1.html#attr-script-type) `text/javascript` is the default type, so you can omit

> The **type** attribute gives the language of the script or format of the
>   data. If the attribute is present, its value must be a valid MIME
>   type. The charset parameter must not be specified. The default, which
>   is used if the attribute is absent, is "text/javascript".

Comment: in other words, omitting it could cause errors in old browsers that does not support HTML5

Answer (score 3):

Well, I am tempted to say that nobody is using `text/javascript` any more, and that even minification tools would probably remove it...
Indeed, [Facebook SDK documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/javascript/quickstart) specifies just `<script>`.

However,
[Google SDK documentation](https://developers.google.com/+/web/signin/add-button-javascript) still has `text/javascript`.

[Amazon SDK documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/guide/browser-examples.html) still has `text/javascript`.

[Linkedin API documentation](https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/javascript-api-tutorial) still has `text/javascript`.

[Instagram](http://instafeedjs.com/) is still using `text/javascript`.

Answer (score 2):

you may be thinking of [this article here](http://www.html5laboratory.com/writing-a-valid-html5-document.php) with the dependency being that scripts default to text/javascript in HTML5 automatically, while non-HTML5 browsers still expect that you define the type specifically spec-wise even though they will almost always guess text/javascript anyways.

Answer (score 2):

> *The HTML5 specification urges authors to omit the attribute rather than provide a redundant MIME type.* [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script)

The [MIME Sniffing Standard](https://mimesniff.spec.whatwg.org/) lets JavaScript be served using any MIME type (*Multipurpose Internet Mail Extensions*) that matches the following:

```
<script type="application/javascript"></script>
<script type="application/ecmascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/ecmascript"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

it's up to the browser to interpret the `script` block correctly based on the headers, i believe, and not the `type` attribute.  So to answer your question, no it is not required for modern browsers (i'm talking IE7+, FF, Webkit).  If you are supporting older browsers than that...I feel sorry for you =)

Comment: Don't forget China with 385+ million users, many of which still use IE6. http://www.netmarketshare.com/report.aspx?qprid=88&sample=51&qpmr=1000

Comment: knowing china's strict internet policy, chances are your site may never reach them =P

Comment: The question is about an inline script, so there are no headers other than the main page (which would be some HTML content type).  Anyway, do you have a source indicating that browsers take into account the headers (e.g. if you have plain <script src="something"></script> and served a VBScript header, is there any browser that would interpret it as VBScript)?

Answer (score 1):

If you're putting a script tag **inside SVG** you **must** specify the type attribute. And it should be `"text/ecmascript"` rather than `"text/javascript"`.

If your script is inline (not linked) you will need to wrap the script body in a CDATA declaration too. The inline script boilerplate for **SVG** (and other XML variants) is thus

```
<script type="text/ecmascript">
<![CDATA[
// your javascript code goes here
]]>
</script>
```

These might be special cases 'in the wild', but they are real enough, and SVG use is growing, so it's incorrect for anyone else to suggest that the type attribute and CDATA are entirely obsolete in modern browsers. The use cases are narrow, yes, but not unheard of.

> "Change the environment to its opposite and every piece of wisdom becomes the worst of folly." - Ashby

Comment: Good call. Just been working on some complex SVG and this is indeed the case!

Answer (score 0):

Well i keep seeing more examples without the text/javascript but for some reason my scripts wont work in FF when i do so. I would recommend keeping the text/javascript declaration. The CDATA tag prevents javascript from being shown as plain text in your website if your browser has javascript turned off. Personally i don't use those tags anymore don't think there's allot of users out there without and if they are out there they might wanna grow some brains :P

Comment: Neither the type attribute nor the old CDATA thing are necessary unless you really want to target truly antique browsers. They shouldn't hurt anything however as long as you really do use the right type.

Comment: I'm using the most recent stable FF release and it seems to have trouble parsing without the declaration of text/javascript, i use jQuery btw but that should not make a difference.

Comment: Well I run my whole web application with script tags that are just plain `<script>`, no "language" and no "type", and they work fine in all browsers. (Well, all reasonable ones: FF, Chrome, Safari, IE, Opera.)

Comment: @pointy seem like FatherStorm just posted an answer to why this is happening. so your comments seems to be incorrect.

Comment: @Michael it may be the case that if you've made the mistake of going with XHTML/Strict you might have a problem, but even then I doubt it. There's general agreement among the luminaries of the JavaScript world that the "type" attribute is unnecessary, and in fact since a bad "type" will break a script, it's just a source of bugs.

Comment: @pointy i'm readying up on the topic and seems your right. I'm not using xhtml so should not have problems, might be coincidence where i make a typo in my code and notice i didn't declare the type. Fix both and in my mind adding the declaration part was the solution. I'm going to drop it from now on and see what happends

Comment: OK - as I said at first, it sure doesn't hurt anything (if it's the right value!) but I like keeping unnecessary stuff out of my pages :-)

Comment: Well crockford states "This attribute is optional. Since Netscape 2, the default programming language in all browsers has been JavaScript. In XHTML, this attribute is required and unnecessary. In HTML, it is better to leave it out. The browser knows what to do. ". Still I keep learning new stuff every day, thx guys :)

Answer (score 0):

`type="text/javascript"` : Required in HTML 4 and XHTML, but optional in HTML5.

`CDATA` : Required in XHTML.

`<!--` : Used to hide the JavaScript from very old browsers. Eg: Netscape 1 and Internet Explorer 2, neither of which anyone uses any more.