# How to load javascript code to an html file at runtime?

Tags: javascript

Let me ask whether it is possible to load javascript code to an html file at runtime. For example , place a textbox to input the location of the script files and a form button to trigger loading the script files.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Paste this within onclick of that button (correct the url in 3rd line):

```
var script = document.createElement("script");
script.setAttribute("type", "text/javascript");
script.setAttribute("src", "url to the script file here");
document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(script);
```

That script will start being downloaded immediately after line 4 is executed, and as soon as it's downloaded it'll execute or otherwise be usable.

Comment: Make sure there is a head element. If not, adding to body works too. Btw, +1 for sticking to pure JavaScript since the question is not tagged with jQuery.

Comment: What if I add two scripts with this method? Will they start downloading at the same time or the second one will wait on the first one?

Comment: This works well. On another note, if you wanted to instead just set the .innerHTML function with the Java Script there instead of setting the 'src' attribute to point to a file, it will extend the length of the HTML page, so to combat this use: "script.setAttribute('hidden', 'true');" to get rid of the added length to the HTMl document.

Comment: Per HTML5 spec, the `type="text/javascript"` attribute is [not necessary](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25737755/4294399).

Answer (score 9):

Yes, the [jQuery getScript method](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/) makes this trivial:

```
//on button click event:
$.getScript(urlOfScript);
```

Alternatively using only native javascript methods:

```
//on button click event:
var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.type = 'text/javascript';
script.src = 'urlOfScript';
head.appendChild(script);
```

Answer (score 2):

All good answers above. You can also load js via ajax as any other html fragment.
Short example:

`start.html`

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <a href="#" onclick="$('#result').load('start.js'); return false;">start</a>
    <div id="result"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

`start.js`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    alert('Hello world!');
</script>
```

You do not need jquery for ajax - I just used it as quick proof of concept.

Answer (score 1):

There is also a jquery method here to achieve the same.

```
let src = 'http://www.example.com/dosome/afsddfa';
$('<script>').attr(
{
   src: src,
   type: 'text/javascript'
}).appendTo('body');
```

It will create a script element and append it to body.

You can also use `.appendTo('head')`.

Answer (score 0):

A 1 liner (just for curiosities):

```
with(document)
with(body)
    with(insertBefore(createElement("script"),firstChild))
        setAttribute("src","//g.alicdn.com/...aplus_v2.js")

//or with additional attributes
with(document)
with(body)
    with(insertBefore(createElement("script"),firstChild))
        setAttribute(
            "exparams","category=...at_bu=cbu",
            id="beacon-aplus",
            src="//g.alicdn.com/...aplus_v2.js")
```