# How to add a script tag to the head section after a specific script tag

Tags: javascript, html, jsp, google-tag-manager

I am using a single page application. I am trying to add a `<script></script>` tag to the head from my nested div in the page after specific javascript code, but I got the error below. Please find my jsp code below.

How to add a script tag after a specific script tag in the head tag from a nested div?

> TypeError: Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': parameter 1 is
>   not of type 'Node'

```
<html>
 <head>

        <!-- Google Tag Manager -->
        <script>
        (function(w, d, s, l, i) {
            w[l] = w[l] || [];
            w[l].push({
                'gtm.start' : new Date().getTime(),
                event : 'gtm.js'
            });
            var f = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0], j = d.createElement(s), dl = l != 'dataLayer' ? '&l='
                    + l
                    : '';
            j.async = true;
            j.src = 'https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id=' + i + dl;
            f.parentNode.insertBefore(j, f);
        })(window, document, 'script', 'dataLayer', 'GTM-5HWKRLC');
        </script>

    **<! Here i need to add another script when my inner div loading !>**

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    ...
    </head>

<body>

    <% String gtm = (String) session.getAttribute("gtmObj"); %>

    <div>
    <script>
        document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild('<script>window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];dataLayer.push(<%=gtm%>)<\/script>');
    </script>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `appendChild` accepts `node` whereas you are passing string. Instead create `script` tag using `document.createElement("script")' and pass it to the appendChild.

Comment: This might be helpful : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9037082/how-to-load-javascript-code-to-an-html-file-at-runtime

Comment: randomSoul - How to add after specific script tag in head tag from nested div

Answer (score 1):

`appendChild` accepts the parameter of type `node` or `HTML element` - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild and you are passing the `string`. Instead create element using `document.createElement`.

```
const script = document.createElement('script');
script.textContent = `window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || []; dataLayer.push('<%=gtm%>')`;

document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
```

To insert the `script` after specific `script` tag, you can add custom attribute and then select that element and use `insertAdjacentElement` to insert new created script after it.

```
// HTML
<script data-id = "myScript"></script>

// Javascript
const script = document.querySelector("script[data-id='myScript']");
const newScript = document.createElement('script');

newScript.textContent = "const a  = 10";

script.insertAdjacentElement('afterend', newScript);
```

Comment: randomSoul - how to add this tag after specific script tag in head tag.i mean  after this <!-- Google Tag Manager -->        <script>

Comment: what is your `specific script tag`?  You can add certain custom attribute to intended `script` and then select that script and use `insertAfter` to append after that `script`.

Comment: @deadend - See edit, I'am sorry actually there is `insertBefore` but no `insertAfter` in javascript.

Comment: @randomSould. Thanks its working. but its showing &quot; instead of  '. eg. &quot;event&quot; instead 'event'. I cant parse textContent .

Comment: use `innerHTML` instead of `textContent`

Comment: Its working. but issue is, when i do inspect element it shows but when i view source code it does not exists

Answer (score 1):

use `document.getElementById("some").insertAdjacentElement('afterend',script);` and add it next to the script tag using `insertAdjacentElement`

```js
var script = document.createElement("script");
script.setAttribute("type", "text/javascript");
script.setAttribute('textContent', '<script>window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];dataLayer.push(<%=gtm%>);dataLayer.push({\'event\':\'Txn\',\'Affiliation\':\'Vehicle\'})<\/script>');

document.getElementById("some").insertAdjacentElement('afterend',script);
```

```html
<html>
<head>

        <!-- Google Tag Manager -->
        <script id="some">
        (function(w, d, s, l, i) {
            w[l] = w[l] || [];
            w[l].push({
                'gtm.start' : new Date().getTime(),
                event : 'gtm.js'
            });
            var f = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0], j = d.createElement(s), dl = l != 'dataLayer' ? '&l='
                    + l
                    : '';
            j.async = true;
            j.src = 'https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id=' + i + dl;
            f.parentNode.insertBefore(j, f);
        })(window, document, 'script', 'dataLayer', 'GTM-5HWKRLC');
        </script>

    </head>

<body>


something
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Syed Mohamed - Thanks. Its adding end of head tag. dataLayer.push({&quot;event&quot;:&quot;Motor-Transaction&quot;. but its showing like as &quot; instead '. and how to add after specific script tag in head tag

Comment: @deadend please post your script content here to check `&quot;` error

Comment: dataLayer.push({&quot;event&quot;:&quot;Txn&quot;,&quot;Affiliation&quot;:&quot;Vehicle&quot})

Comment: @deadend updated the code to bring up the `'`(quotes) with escape sequence

Comment: Its working. but issue is, when i do inspect element it shows my included script but when i view source code it does not exists

Comment: it is a javascript code, it will not be shown in source code. it will only be available in js not in html.

Comment: Noted with Thanks