# ReferenceError when calling a regular javascript function as a callback from JQuery.get

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to use a javascript function defined outside of the $(document).ready(function(){}); as the callback for a $.get() request. However, firebug shows:

```
ReferenceError: temp is not defined
    $.get('twitter.php', function(data){temp(data)});
```

Here's the relevant code:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
<script type="txt/javascript">       
    function temp(data){
        alert(data);
    }
</script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $.get('twitter.php', function(data){temp(data)});
    });
</script>
```

`twitter.php` does return data.

Comment: do not use script type="". It is not needed.

Comment: @AndyRay - At least not in `html5`, but older doc types still require it.

Comment: @TravisJ incorrect http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5265202/do-you-need-text-javascript-specified-in-your-script-tags it's just one of those unexpected things that works in all places

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have your script type set to `'txt/javascript'`, if I'm not mistaen, it should be `'text/javascript'`, also you need a semicolon after your function.

```
<script type="text/javascript">       
    function temp(data){
        alert(data);
    };
</script>
```

Comment: The semicolon is not required. It would only be necessary if the function were assigned to a variable.

Answer (score 3):

Remove `type="txt/javascript"`, or change it to `text/javascript`.

Answer (score 2):

put

```
 function temp(data){
    alert(data);
 }
```

above

```
$(document).ready(function(){

});
```

Comment: i mean your relevant code must be `<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">       
    function temp(data){
        alert(data);
    };
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $.get('twitter.php', function(data){temp(data)});
    });
</script>`

Answer (score 1):

You have a small syntax error which causes the script to be invalid, `type="txt/javascript"` should be:

```
<script type="text/javascript">       
 function temp(data){
    alert(data);
 }
</script>
```