# Browser compatibility on pure <script> tag

Tags: javascript, html

There are a few posts like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5265202/do-you-need-text-javascript-specified-in-your-script-tags) said HTML5 does not require the type attribute, but my question is:

**Q. If I leave the type today, what browser will break my page (ignore the validation part)?**

Are there any tested data?

Comment: Unless you use the strictmode in your pages, no middle aged browser will break your page.