# object has no method setup jwplayer

Tags: javascript, html, pug, jwplayer

I am calling this javascript file from jade

```
-if ...

-else
  div#container
  script(type='text/javascript')
    jwplayer('container').setup({       

     file: '/path/to/file.m3u8',
     width: '0',
     height: '0'
    });
```

Uncaught TypeError: Object # has no method 'setup'

and the same javascript file is in the header as well.

Comment: are you  sure that `container` the `id` of the element?

Comment: yup I am actually in jade so it is done by div#container

Answer (score 0):

You need to put pug into Plain Text mode with a period at the end of the script tag, otherwise it will try to render more DOM elements underneath it.  Script isn't a reserved word in pug, it just renders it like any other HTML element and pug doesn't know that what follows is JavaScript (that's a good thing IMO)

Adding the period to the end of a tag tells pug that it should render everything contained in the tag as plain text. If you want to use pug variables in a plain text section you need to use [interpolation](https://pugjs.org/language/interpolation.html).

This will work for you:

```
  script.
    jwplayer('container').setup({       

     file: '/path/to/file.m3u8',
     width: '0',
     height: '0'
    });
```

Also, you don't need to add the type property any more on script elements ([details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5265202/do-you-need-text-javascript-specified-in-your-script-tags)).