# Linking to a external file in javascript an easy one

Tags: javascript

So I'm attempting to teach my self some javascript stuff, which I plan to lead towards JQuery for my new job, and I've got a simple question as I'm attempting to work it out.

Here's my stuff.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<script src="myScriptDemo3.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<h3>Referencing an external Javascript file</h3>
<p id="demo">Pre script render</p>

<button type="button" onclick="myFunction()"> Try it!</button>

<p><strong>Note:</strong> myFunction is stored in an external file called "myScriptDemo3.js"</p>    
</body>

</html>
```

My external script reads.

```
function myFunction()
{
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML= "Post render";
{
```

The problem is that when I click the button, it's not changing the  Pre render Script

to read "post render" . Not sure why, again I know it's a simple thing but any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Always be sure to open up your browser's dev tools to catch typos like this. Chrome clearly shows a `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input` error message in the console.

Comment: you should also set the type of the script tag to type="text/javascript"

Comment: @Gimmy: the `type` attribute is unnecessary in this case. [See here for more info](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5265202/do-you-need-text-javascript-specified-in-your-script-tags)

Answer (score 2):

You have a syntax error in your external script. The ending `{` should be `}`.

```
function myFunction()
{
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML= "Post render";
}
```

Comment: always check your browser console to see if there are any syntax errors..