# JS doesn't fire in IE does in Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery

The following code doesn't seem to work in IE (using 9) - Test 1 fires but test 2 does not. Is there a different way of doing this for IE?

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    overlay = $("#overlay");
    img = $("#myimg");
    alert('test 1');
    img.load(function () {
        alert('test 2');
        var myPercent = 50;
        var myHeight = $("#myimg").height() / 100 * myPercent;  
        overlay.height(myHeight);
        overlay.width($("#myimg").width());
        $(".percent").css('margin-top', $("#myimg").height()/2 - $(".percent").height()/2);
        $(".percent").text(myPercent + "%");
    });
});
</script>
```

EDIT: Fixed it by using $(window).load(function() { instead of document ready and removing the function

Comment: Surely this will only work if the image has not already loaded when the document is loaded and is therefore dependant on the browser speed and image caching?

Comment: Did you make sure the image wasn't already loaded when attaching the event? try to first set the event then attach `src` of the image.

Comment: Try commenting out all of the code except for what's needs for your `alerts`. Also, your opening script tag should be `<script type="text/javascript">`.

Comment: Also, it says right in the jQuery docs that this event does not work reliably cross-browser. http://api.jquery.com/load-event/ You may want to consider a different approach (loading the images with javascript, for instance).

Comment: @TomBeech Please accept one of the answers or add an answer by yourself to complete this question.

Comment: @matthewpavkov `type="text/javascript"` is unnecessary

Comment: @Ian If it's `XHTML` then it's required for validation (though still not needed, as you said). If it's `HTML`, there's no point in including it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5265202/do-you-need-text-javascript-specified-in-your-script-tags

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Technically you should be able to add onload parameter on img tag which calls js function that does the same thing. I haven't tested this but it's worth a shot.

```
...

<script>
  function resizeImg ($img) {
    // code
  }
</script>

...

<img onload="resizeImg($(this));" src="foo.png" />
```

You might as well use jQuery then.

```
...

<script>
  $("#fooImg").load(function () {
    // code
  });
</script>

...

<img id="fooImg" src="foo.png" />
```

Comment: I have to do it on the load otherwise the width/height are always 0

Answer (score 2):

From the jQuery API of [.load()](http://api.jquery.com/load-event/)

> Caveats of the load event when used with images
>
> A common challenge developers attempt to solve using the .load()
>   shortcut is to execute a function when an image (or collection of
>   images) have completely loaded. There are several known caveats with
>   this that should be noted. These are:
>
> It doesn't work consistently nor reliably cross-browser
>
> It doesn't fire correctly in WebKit if the image src is set to the
>   same src as before
>
> It doesn't correctly bubble up the DOM tree Can cease to fire for
>   images that already live in the browser's cache

---

Make use of `$(window).load()`:

```
$(window).load(function() {
    alert('test 2');
    var myPercent = 50;
    var myHeight = $("#myimg").height() / 100 * myPercent;  
    overlay.height(myHeight);
    overlay.width($("#myimg").width());
    $(".percent").css('margin-top', $("#myimg").height()/2 - $(".percent").height()/2);
    $(".percent").text(myPercent + "%");
});
```

Comment: Ah - Is there a different way of doing it?

Comment: I believe `$(document).ready()` is when all the structure of the document is loaded (doesn't include images), but `$(window).load()` is when ALL the resources of the page (including images) are fully loaded.

Comment: "The document ready event executes already when the HTML-Document is loaded and the DOM is ready, even if all the graphics haven’t loaded yet. (...) The window load event executes a bit later when the complete page is fully loaded, including all frames, objects and images." [**REFERENCE**](http://4loc.wordpress.com/2009/04/28/documentready-vs-windowload/)

Comment: So in THAT case, the `.load()`-event should bind successfully. But it doesn't fire which means he has to put that stuff into the `$(window).ready()`

Comment: Take a better look at his code... He is binding the load event to the image, not the window...

Comment: @silentw Use @[USER] to mention the corresponding user. Again, the `.load()`-function is the worst solution on images.

Comment: @FabioPoloni Guess I already knew that :) Please, justify why the `.load()` handler is the worst solution...

Comment: @silentw I misunderstood something and edited my comment: *... is the worst solution on images.*

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind using a plugin, [Paul Irish](https://gist.github.com/paulirish/268257) made a simple plugin to handle image loading, seeing as [.load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/) does not handle images. The plugin was moved and turned into a project which can be found on [GitHub](https://github.com/desandro/imagesloaded).

```
$.fn.imagesLoaded = function (callback) {
    var elems = this.filter('img'),
        len = elems.length,

    // data uri bypasses webkit log warning (thx doug jones (cjboco))
    blank = "data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAP///ywAAAAAAQABAAACAUwAOw==";

    elems.bind('load', function () {
        // check image src to prevent firing twice (thx doug jones (cjboco))
        if (--len <= 0 && this.src !== blank) {
            callback.call(elems, this);
        }
    }).each(function () {

        // cached images don't fire load sometimes, so we reset src.
        if (this.complete || this.complete === undefined) {
            var src = this.src;

            // webkit hack from http://groups.google.com/group/jquery-dev/browse_thread/thread/eee6ab7b2da50e1f
            this.src = blank;
            this.src = src;
        }
    });
};
```

You can see it in action at this fiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/denniswaltermartinez/c4DMH/

Answer (score -3):

img.load() as an event is not supported by IE. Actually it is not necessary, that $(document).ready() function has already ensure img and other elements loaded. Just remove it.

Comment: Ah, when I remove it, the height and wdith always return as 0