# Can we find count of element in array using javascript?

Tags: javascript

I want   to   find   Count   Of  specific    element   in   array   using   JavaScript
for   example   [2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3]    count   of   2   is   3   and   count  of   3  is   5.

Answer (score 1):

```
var map = {};
var arr = [2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3];
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (map[arr[i]]) {
        map[arr[i]]++;
    } else {
        map[arr[i]] = 1;
    }
}
for(var key in map){
 console.log("occurence of "+ key+" = "+map[key]);
}
```

**Output:** 
occurence of 2 = 3 
        occurence of 3 = 5

Comment: Depending on your state of mind, `map[arr[i]] = (map[arr[i]] || 0) + 1;` is more compact.

Answer (score 0):

Just for fun (works only with strings and numbers).

```
[2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3].join().match(/3/g).length; // return 5
```

Comment: only works for single-digit integers: [2,2,2,3,3,3,3,33].join().match(/3/g).length is 6 and not 4

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
function searchInArray(someInt, someArray){
    var count = 0;
    for(var i in someArray){
        if(someArray[i] === someInt){
            count++;
        }
    }
    return count;
}
searchInArray(2, [2,2,2,2,2,3,4,4,4,5]);
//returns 5
```

Answer (score 0):

In pure JavaScript:

```
function countOccurrences(array) {
    var occurrences = {};
    for (var i = 0, l = array.length; i < l; i++) {
        if (occurrences[array[i]] === undefined) {
            occurrences[array[i]] = 1;
        }
        else {
            occurrences[array[i]]++;
        }
    }
    return occurrences;
}

var test = [2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,4,4,5];

console.log(countOccurrences(test));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a loop.

```
var thisChar;
var thisCharCount;
for (var i = 0; i < yourArray.length; i++) {
    if(yourArray[i] == thisChar)
    thisCharCount++;
}
```

Depending if you compare to set or dynamic comparable values, use a array.

Answer (score 0):

Use Underscore:

```
_.groupBy([2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3])
> {2: [2,2,2], 3: [3,3,3,3,3]}
```

Then count the length of the arrays.

Do it yourself using `Array#reduce`:

```
function counts(array) {
    return array.reduce(function(prev, current) {
        prev[current] = (prev[current] || 0) + 1;
        return prev;
    }, {});
}
> counts([2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3]) // {2: 3, 3: 5}
```

To count occurrences of a specific `val`:

```
function count(array, val) {
    for (var i=0, index=0; (index = array.indexOf(val, index)) !==-1;  i++) { }
    return i;
}
```

Or if you prefer

```
function count(array, val) {
    var i=0, index=0;
    while ((index = array.indexOf(val, index)) !== -1) { i++; }
    return i;
}
```

Or perhaps recursively?

```
function count(array, val) {
    var index = array.indexOf(val);
    return index === -1 ? 0 : count(array.slice(index), val) + 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not using jQuery:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    var count2 = 0, count3 = 0;
    $.each([2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3], function( index, value ) {
        if(value==2)
            count2++;
        if(value==3)
            count3++;
    });
    alert("2:"+count2);
    alert("3:"+count3);
});
```

Comment: Yes, only jQuery can do loops. By the way, `type=javascript` is not necessary. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5265202/do-you-need-text-javascript-specified-in-your-script-tags.