# Import JS files and Javascript in XSLT

Tags: javascript, xml, xslt

I have this `xsl` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="html"/>
    <xsl:template match="/scenario">
        <html>
            <head>
                <script type="text/javascript" src="html5.js"> </script>
                <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js"> </script>
                <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.details.js"> </script>
                <script type="text/javascript">
                    <xsl:text>
                    window.console || (window.console = { 'log': alert });
                    $(function() {
                        $('html').addClass($.fn.details.support ? 'details' : 'no-details');
                        $('body').prepend($.fn.details.support ? 'Native support detected; the plugin will only add ARIA annotations and fire custom open/close events.' : 'Emulation active; you are watching the plugin in action!');
                        $('details').details();
                        $('details').on({
                            'open.details': function() {
                                console.log('opened');
                            },
                            'close.details': function() {
                                console.log('closed');
                            }
                        });
                    });
                    </xsl:text>
                </script>
                <style type="text/css">
                    body {
                    font-size: 90%
                    }
                    .mainScenario {
                    padding : 10px;
                    border: 2px solid #002588;
                    }
                    .mainScnName {
                    font-weight: bold;
                    font-size: larger;
                    color : #6632ff;
                    }
                    .mainScnDesc {
                    font-weight: bold;
                    font-size: larger;
                    color : #3312aa;
                    }
                    .subScenario {
                    border: 2px solid #0032ff;
                    padding : 10px;
                    }
                    .subScnName {
                    font-weight: bold;
                    font-size: larger;
                    color : #6632ff;
                    }
                    .subScnDesc {
                    font-weight: bold;
                    font-size: larger;
                    color : #3312aa;
                    }
                    .command {
                    margin-left : 20px;
                    }
                </style>
            </head>
            <body>
                <div class="mainScenario">
                    <pre>
                        <b><xsl:value-of select="./greeting"/></b>
                        <details>
                            <summary class="mainScnName">Name: <xsl:value-of select="@name"/></summary>
                            <p class="mainScnDesc">Description: <xsl:value-of select="@description"/></p>
                            <xsl:for-each select="./*">
                                <xsl:apply-templates select="."/>
                            </xsl:for-each>
                        </details>
                    </pre>
                </div>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="scenario">
        <div class="subScenario">
            <b><xsl:value-of select="./greeting"/></b>
            <pre>
                <details>
                    <summary class="subScnName">Name: <xsl:value-of select="@name"/></summary>
                    <p class="subScnDesc">Description: <xsl:value-of select="@description"/></p>
                    <xsl:for-each select="./*">
                        <xsl:apply-templates select="."/>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </details>
            </pre>
        </div>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The output for Javascript and JS file import part in firefox is this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="html5.js"><script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js"/><script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.details.js"/><script type="text/javascript">
    window.console || (window.console = { 'log': alert });
    $(function() {
        $('html').addClass($.fn.details.support ? 'details' : 'no-details');
        $('body').prepend($.fn.details.support ? 'Native support detected; the plugin will only add ARIA annotations and fire custom open/close events.' : 'Emulation active; you are watching the plugin in action!');
        $('details').details();
        $('details').on({
            'open.details': function() {
                console.log('opened');
            },
            'close.details': function() {
                console.log('closed');
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

I have no idea why the parser assumes all the tags are children of the first tag!!!

I should mention that the scripts are trying to enable `details` tag in firefox and IE. I copied them from [this url](https://github.com/mathiasbynens/jquery-details). This sample works in my computer.

**EDIT 1:**

I have changed line `<xsl:output method="html"/>` into `<xsl:output method="html" omit-xml-declaration="yes/>`; but it did not affect the rendered HTML file. Secondly I've added `<xsl:comment/>` between empty `script` tags; this try rendered tags as I wanted:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="html5.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.details.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.console || (window.console = { 'log': alert });
    $(function() {
        $('html').addClass($.fn.details.support ? 'details' : 'no-details');
        $('body').prepend($.fn.details.support ? 'Native support detected; the plugin will only add ARIA annotations and fire custom open/close events.' : 'Emulation active; you are watching the plugin in action!');
        $('details').details();
        $('details').on({
            'open.details': function() {
                console.log('opened');
            },
            'close.details': function() {
                console.log('closed');
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

But There is a problem yet; the scripts does not work.

**EDIT 2:**

Well, I finally get that working; there was a problem in addressing js files. I also added some styles into the `<head>` tag as below:

```
<style>
    summary { cursor: pointer; }
    .no-details details > * { display: none; }
    .no-details details > summary:before { float: left; width: 20px; content: '► '; }
    .no-details details.open > summary:before { content: '▼ '; }
    .no-details details summary { display: block; }
</style>
```

And I have added `<meta charset="utf-8"/>` in the first line after `<head>`. The arrow signs are not showing in the page. Is there anything wrong with the character encoding or what?

**EDIT 3:**

I also tried `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">`; nothing changed.

Comment: I'm not seeing where the first `script` tag with the `src="http://www.fileswap...` is being generated in your XSLT.

Comment: Scripts do not work how?

Comment: @torazaburo, I have just copied the wrong text. Edited the question. About not working, as I said in the document, it should render `detail` tag in the firefox; "not working" actually means it's not rendering it properly.

Comment: Well, there is a graceful fallback for old browsers that do not support `details`, which is, just let them not support it, I mean, the world will not come to an end. Anyway, I suspect this problem is not connected to XSLT, and its roots lie elsewhere. I guess I don't need to ask you if there are no console errors. Has the `no-details` class been added to the `html` tag?

Comment: @torazaburo, Yes. `class` property in the `html` tag has been set to `no-details`.

Comment: Well, then the script **is** working. Do you actually have `details` elements in your document, he asks stupidly. Do the details elements start off closed, as one would expect if the plug-in is operating on them, and have little arrows to their left? Off-topic, but FWIW http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5265202/do-you-need-text-javascript-specified-in-your-script-tags.

Comment: @torazaburo, I have some edits. Please review.

Comment: Well, now you're down to debugging CSS. I'm not convinced the non-summary parts are **ever** going to be displayed; don't you need something like `.no-details details.open > * { display: default; }`? Also, no need to `float: left` the `:before` rule, although I doubt it would hurt anything.

Comment: @torazaburo, you are right; none of them are displayed when the page is opening and clicking on them make them visible.It's what I want. Removing `float: left` changed nothing.

Comment: @torazaburo, after some googling I find out that the firefox has removed the `utf-8` encoding since firefox 28. That is the problem. I'll mark your answer as it resolved the main issue of the question; thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In HTML script tags are not self-closing. Try specifying the output method, which I see you did, but you  will also need to omit the xml declaration:

```
<xsl:output method="html" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
```

That will also mean that `img` tags etc. are not self-closed, which ought to be OK.

A less optimal work-around would be to do

```
<script src="..."><xsl:comment/></script>
```

but that will litter your HTML with `<!-- -->` comments.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the workaround is simply this:

```
<script src="//whatever.com/script.js">&nbsp;</script>
```

Edit:

```
<script src="//whatever.com/script.js">&#160;</script>
```

Comment: I believe the XSL processor will choke on that entity.