# Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND loading json.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I am testing an html webpage and it is failing to load a local jquery.json-2.4.0.js. I am testing the html page locally from chrome. When the page loaded I get a ***net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND.***

Why is it unable to load the file? This file has been moved from a different server (which it was working fine on), but the directory paths are the same (I double checked the path ).

Here is my line:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='/webforms/ExperianEmailJsScripts/jquery/js/jquery.jsonp-2.4.0.js'></script>
```

Comment: Try another browser than Chrome. If error disappears it is an issue of Chrome outside control of Javascript. Also Window may change filenames.

Comment: Update: there is a solution on GitHub [here](https://github.com/parcel-bundler/parcel/issues/470#issuecomment-354734896).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This error means that file was not found. Either path is wrong or file is not present where you want it to be. Try to access it by entering source address in your browser to check if it really is there. Browse the directories on server to ensure the path is correct. You may even copy and paste the relative path to be certain it is alright.

Comment: Are you sure the source address is okay? Look for a type'o, missing directory, etc.

Comment: make sure your .js file is not a text file.

Answer (score 22):

Remove the first `/` in the path. Also you don't need `type="text/javascript"` anymore in HTML5.

Comment: still doesn't want to load the file

Comment: OK, try using the full path of the file, just for the moment. E.g. if you're on Windows it might be file:///C:/..../something.js

Comment: Do you have sources to support that `type="text/javascript"` is optionnal in HTML5?

Comment: @D4V1D Sure, take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5265202/do-you-need-text-javascript-specified-in-your-script-tags.

Comment: @Zak: Thanks for that! I'll leave it out from now on.

Comment: Upvoted it, although I'm not sure that the leading `/` is the problem. It'll do for the optional `text/javascript` then (good luck in your way from getting to editing reviews soon :))

Comment: Thanks, I suspect that the real problem is that some directory is misnamed! Quite hard to tell though without being on the OP's computer.

Comment: @Zak Hi zak I have a similar problem, how different is this problem when deploying in windows vs. in ubuntu? On ubuntu, it runs fine without any problems but on windows i also obtained the error as D4V1D.

Answer (score 3):

I got the same error using:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:400,400i,700,700i,900,900i" type="text/css" media="all">
```

But once I added **https:** in the beginning of the href the error disappeared.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:400,400i,700,700i,900,900i" type="text/css" media="all">
```

Answer (score 2):

Sometime when you downloading a project from other people, they might have some special customization. So, in my case I downloaded this project https://github.com/thecodercoder/fem-easybank

And got these errors: Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
[image: Errors]
That happed because the creator was using the /dist folder customization.

[image: SOLUTION]

https://youtu.be/aoQ6S1a32j8?t=309

SOLUTION: you open Notepad++  press: Ctrl + F  for search
find all folders that starts with / as in the picture and replace with norma ones like:
/dist/  to   dist

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Same thing happened to me. Eventually my solution was to navigate to the repository using terminal (on mac) and create a new js file with a slightly different name. It linked immediately so i copied contents of original file to new one. You also might want to lose the first `/` after `src=` and use `""`.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

`path.join(__dirname, '/dcp-electron/index.html')`

you should add a dot at the start of the path, to indicate that the path is relative:

`path.join(__dirname, './dcp-electron/index.html')`

Answer (score 0):

this can happen when you have the base tag, as explained in other answers

```
 <base href="/">
```